# How to compare a string variable with a date variable

Tags: vb.net, datetime, string-comparison

```
   Dim strLastDate as string ' fill this value from database field 
   Dim TodayDate as Date = Format(Now.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

- here

  `strLastDate = "16/07/2014 04:39:10"`

  and

  `TodayDate =17/07/2014"`
- How can I compare these dates? Based upon the result I have to show an alert.

Comment: you should turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: The database field you mention should really be stored as a DateTime value, in which case you can retrieve it as a DateTime and check `If lastDate.Date = todayDate.Date Then...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Private Sub CompareDates(ByVal strLastDate As String)
    'as you said strLastDate is getting from database 
    'lets assume strLastDate = "16/07/2014 04:39:10"
    Dim dteToday As Date = CDate(Format(Now.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
    Dim dateDiffer As Integer
    Dim dteLastdate As Date
    'formats the strLastDate like "dd/MM/yyyy"
    strLastDate = strLastDate.Substring(0, 10) 'you'll get 16/07/2014
    'converts string to date 
    dteLastdate = CDate(strLastDate)
    'now Compare  dteToday with dteLastdate
    dateDiffer = dteToday.Subtract(dteLastdate).TotalDays
    If dateDiffer > 2 Then
        'your alert message is here
    End If
End Sub
```